# Postgres - How to search and aggregate from a JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have an asset_quantities table as below

```
id   |   asset_type   |    quantity   |    site_id   |   asset_ids_json
  1      'Container'           3              1             [{"id":1,"make":"am1","model":"amo1"},{"id":2,"make":"am1","model":"amo2"},{"id":3,"make":"am3","model":"amo3"}]
  2      'Cage'                3              1             [{"id":4,"make":"bm1","model":"bmo1"},{"id":5,"make":"bm2","model":"bmo2"},{"id":6,"make":"bm2","model":"cmo3"}]
  3      'Crate'               3              1             [{"id":7,"make":"cm1","model":"cmo1"},{"id":8,"make":"cm1","model":"cmo1"},{"id":9,"make":"cm1","model":"cmo2"}]
```

I want to write a SQL query in Postgres that will give me the quantity count of each asset type for a given make or model.

E.g. If I wanted to fetch the quantity for each asset type where make='am1',

```
site_id   |   Container_qty    |     Cage_qty     |     Crate_qty
   1               2                     0                  0
```

E.g. If I wanted to fetch the quantity for each asset type where make='cm1', the result set would look like

```
site_id   |   Container_qty    |     Cage_qty     |     Crate_qty
   1               0                     0                  3
```

I have written the query below to pivot the values from the 'asset_type' rows into columns but can't figure out how to filter and aggregate the counts based on the attributes inside the field 'asset_ids_json'. It is safe to assume that the length of the json array inside asset_ids_json will always be the same as the value in the 'quantity' column.

```
select
  aq.site_id, 
  sum(case when aq.asset_type = 'Container' then aq.quantity end) container_qty,
  sum(case when aq.asset_type = 'Cage' then aq.quantity end) cage_qty ,
  sum(case when aq.asset_type = 'Crate' then aq.quantity end) crate_qty,
from asset_quantities aq
group by aq.site_id;
```

The crux of my question is how can I filter & aggregate results based on the attributes inside the json column 'asset_ids_json'. I'm using Postgres 9.4.

Comment: It looks like your expected results don't match your sample data.  Is that true?  Also, id is not unique?  Is (id, asset_type) unique?

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, you are right. I've updated the question with the correct expected results. And yes, id is unique now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=2d10036ce94b8306f3fbaa4cde637a30)

```
SELECT
    site_id,
    SUM(case when asset_type = 'Container' then quantity end) container_qty,
    SUM(case when asset_type = 'Cage' then quantity end) cage_qty ,
    SUM(case when asset_type = 'Crate' then quantity end) crate_qty
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
        site_id,
        asset_type,
        quantity
    FROM asset_quantities aq,
        json_array_elements(asset_ids_json)
    WHERE value ->> 'make' = 'cm1'
) s
GROUP BY site_id
```

To get a `WHERE` clause over the content of a JSON array you have to expand the array. `json_array_elements()` creates one row for each element. With that it is possible to ask for a certain value.

Because of this expansion the current rows are multiplied (three times here because there are three elements in the array). Because you are only interested in the original `site_id`, `asset_type` and `quantity` data which were simply copied into the new records, you can eliminate them with a `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT ON` checks for distinct values of each `id`. So if two JSON array would contain the same key/value both will be saved.

Comment: Thanks S-man for the query. I am still getting a value of 3 for container_qty when I search for make = 'am1'. I should only get 2 in that case. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Just in case my question wasn't clear, I am basically looking to aggregate the {ASSET_TYPE}_qty column based on the number of json objects of a specific make or model in the json array. E.g. If I want to fetch the number of asset types of type 'Container' whose make is 'am1', then I should get the value 2 for 'container_qty'

Comment: Then instead of `SUM `you need the `COUNT` (and do not need the `DISTINCT` clause as well): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=d3e068593317ff75bd33bd69165d0bd9